# XAML ComboBox Selected Item Background Color in Windows 10

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, windows-10, controltemplate

I'm relatively new to WPF and XAML and have encountered a problem with ComboBox and background color in Windows 10.  I have created a ComboBox Control Template and this largely solves my problem.  However, when opening the ComboBox, the item that is the currently selected item has a light colored background that makes it difficult to read because the foreground is white.  I need to make the selected item's background darker.  I've searched for answers to no avail.  What am I missing?

This is what I am currently seeing:

[image]

Here is the ComboBox declaration:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_comboBoxUserName" Height="23" Margin="4" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="_userName_SelectionChanged" 
   IsEditable="True" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
   Foreground="{StaticResource BrushICWhite}" 
   Background="{StaticResource BrushICBlue}" 
   Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxCT}" 
   ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
```

And here is the ComboBox Control Template:
EDIT: I edited the template to include SolidColorBrush elements that I have added.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxCT" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="Placement" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Placement}">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
                    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RoundCorners="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,0L3.5,4 7,0z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="RenderFocused" TargetName="Border" Value="True"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelected.Background" Color="#005f7e"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelected.Border" Color="#005f7e"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedHover.Background" Color="#005f7e"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedHover.Border" Color="#005f7e"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Background" Color="#005f7e"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Border" Color="#005f7e"/>    
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushICBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushICBlue}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `SelectionBrush` property of the `TextBox` in the `ControlTemplate` to a `Brush` of your choice:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
SelectionBrush="Black">
```

You may also want to set the `SelectionOpacity` property of the same TextBox to 1.

**Edit:**

You need to override the template of the `ComboBoxItem`. Change the `Color` of the "ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Background" `SolidColorBrush`:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHover.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHover.Border" Color="#A826A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelected.Background" Color="Black"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelected.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedHover.Background" Color="#2E0080FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedHover.Border" Color="#99006CD9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Background" Color="Red"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewFocus.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHoverFocus.Background" Color="#5426A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHoverFocus.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushICBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushICBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHover.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHover.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelected.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelected.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedHover.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedHover.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewFocus.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHoverFocus.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHoverFocus.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sadly, that did not fix it for me.  In the inserted image, the problem is that combobox has been clicked on and there are two items in the list.  The top item is the current item and looks blank white but it is showing white numbers on a very light grey background.  I need the background of that list item to be dark.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a reproducible sample of your issue? Read this and edit your question accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You reference some brushes that haven't included and there are no items in the sample ComboBox you have posted.

Comment: I seem to be describing my problem poorly.  The problem is not with the textbox portion of the ComboBox but with the List Items.  There are two items in the list.  The two items contain the numbers 18015551777 and 14004441444,  The first item is the currently selected item so the contents of that item - 18015551777 - are showing in the textbox portion of the combobox.  But, as you can see, you can't read the first item in the item list because the background is too light for the white foreground.  The second list item, shows just fine because it is using the specified background color.

Comment: Is it the item that you move the mouse pointer over that is too light?

Comment: The mouse is not hovering over any of the items. The one that is too light is the default item.

Comment: Ok. You need to override the template of the ComboBoxItem. See my edit.

Comment: I added a SolidColorBrush for:
ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Background and ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedNoFocus.Border.  I set the color of both of them to the same color as BrushICBlue.  Still, the selected item has a light background.  Where can I find a reference that describes all the possible x:key options?

Comment: Did you really set the Template property of your ComboBoxItemStyle? Please edit your question and include your full style and a sample ComboBox that uses it.

Comment: I edited the template to include the SolidColorBrush elements that I am now trying.

Comment: Just copy the template I provided and change the colours of the brushes.

Comment: Mea culpa! I took you statement to override the SolidColorBrush too literally.  I have copied the entire template and that has solved my problem.  Thank you for your forbearance and persistence.